# Access windows 7 guest http port from linux host with virtualbox (using redmine and rails)

Tags: networking, windows-7, virtualbox, redmine, http-server

I've just installed redmine on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 running on VirtualBox 5.2.12 r122571

I disabled windows firewall.

The host and the guest can ping each other.

I start redmine using webrick:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

From the guest I can access the app with `localhost:3000` and with `127.0.0.1:3000`, but not using the guest ip address

From the host I can ping the guest, but I cannot access it using `<guest_ip_address>:3000`

I tried with node's http_serve and it works ok, I can browse it from the guest and from the host using `<guest_ip_address>:8080`

Is there some ruby/rails/webrick configuration missing somewhere???

--

This is my configuration

Host machine: Linux antergos 4.16.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 9 11:25:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

VirtualBox version: 5.2.12 r122571

Guest machine: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Network: bridged

Redmine version: 3.4.5.stable

Ruby version: 2.3.3-p222 (2016-11-21) [x64-mingw32]

Rails version: 4.2.8

Answer (score 0):

One way I could find to solve it is to explicitly specify the ip address to bind to like this:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -b <guest_ip_address> -p 3000
```

That way I can access it using the ip of the guest, but I can no longer use localhost from the guest.

Still not sure if this is the best solution, I'd like to be able to use localhost and 127.0.0.1 from the guest and the guest's ip from the host.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to drop webrick and use thin.

According to [this](https://www.benkirane.ch/deployment-rails-4-app-windows/) guide you have to:

Edit `<redmine_folder>/Gemfile` file and add:

gem "thin"

Then run

```
$> bundle install
```

After that you can start it with

```
$>thin start -e production
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Especificación de unidad no válida.
```

And then I can start it from the guest with `localhost:3000`, `127.0.0.1:3000` or `<guest_ip_address>:3000`, and from the host with `<guest_ip_address>:3000`

Also, the application seems to be much more responsive than with Webrick